# How can I see full conversation history in flex by twilio?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I am using flex by twilio to receive and send whatsapp messages to clients.
At the moment, when a new message from client comes in (it's called task in flex),
I can only see messages from the current conversations.
How can I see full history of our conversation in the chat screen?
I've tried to google it and to contact their support but no answer.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A conversation is removed from the Conversation list once it is completed.

But the messaging history through the SMS channel is logged so you will have to check the `Programmable Messaging Logs`. (Each log is one message)